# Cannot acces post data sent from okhttp from php

Tags: php, android, okhttp

i send post request with a json object to php in server, but php keep telling $_POST is empty.

this is okhttp code

```
    public String postConection(JSONObject pJson, String pUrl) throws IOException {
    final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String dirArchivo = "http://10.0.2.2/SoulStoreProject/"+pUrl;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, pJson.toString());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(dirArchivo)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

and this is the php code

```
$nick = $_POST['nick'];
$password = $_POST['password']; 

$query = "
    INSERT INTO 
        players(nick, password) 
        VALUES($nick,$password)
    ";


$DB->Execute($query);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but usually POST variables are send in the HTTP header, not as JSON in the request...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are posting in JSON format so you need to grab the post with `file_get_contents('php://input')` and then decode it so that you have it as an array.

`$_POST` only works with posts that are encoded with `enctype=”multipart/form-data”`

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

$nick = $post['nick'];
$password = $post['password']; 

$query = "INSERT INTO players(nick, password) VALUES(?,?)";
$sth = $DB->prepare($query);
$sth->Execute(array($nick, $password));
```

Comment: thanks man, that got rid of the error, but i cant insert into de DB, may the array by empty still?

Comment: try `var_dump($post)` or `print_r($post)` to see if there is anything in the post array

Comment: I've also added an edit to my answer to show that you need to [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) the statment if you are using PDO

Comment: this is the dump from $post:

<b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
                                                                                     'nick' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'eeeee'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
                                                                                     'password' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'rrrrrr'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
                                                                                   </pre><br />

Comment: Just do `echo $nick;` after the line `$nick = $post['nick'];` and see if it prints.

Comment: it does, the variable $nick is set with the string coming from the android app. Just dont insert. I'll figure it out somehow haha thanks man again saved my day

Comment: did you see my edit that I made to my answer about preparing the query?

Comment: yes and i changed mine, thks for that as well but the problem persist :/